# %100 free file manager Android app with http server feature

Tags: android, file-management

I am looking for free file manager Android app can create http server web interface. No ads , no in app purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I use X-plore.  I dont recall the last time I saw an ad on it.

[X-plore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&gl=US)  It has a nice interface.

[image]

Comment: thanks when I acess its http interface it display a message to me to pay

Comment: From memory, it only asks for a donation, which was optional.  Even if its not optional, you can donate what you like.